# React native web support

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-web

I have project in react native and it was build in iOS and android successfully. I have not used react native cli for that project. Now I have to give support for web. So when I run the app all functionality should work in web same as in iOS and android. I have follow tutorial for that
https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-integrate-react-native-web-existing-react-native-apps-8e4964ad2f0b
But when I run in the web it getting blank page.
I have tried many ways but it getting blank page. It is possible to run the app in web without using expo?
Please help.

Comment: could you please share more info? like console tab error. list of packages you use and stuffs like this

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use expo, i suggest you to use this [react-native-web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web)

Comment: This should be a comment, no need to add it as separate answer.

Comment: I can't comment because i have less than 50 reputation